# how to combine a texture on a cylinder in papervision3d?

Tags: actionscript-3, textures, papervision3d

I would like to combine bitmaps to one texture and apply it to a cylindric primitive.
The cylinder will be rotating or better: the texture should moving along the cylindric-surface and therefor you should see only one (up to 3 textures at the same time).
For better understanding: it's my intention to create somehow a poster-pillow with a undefined number of posters on it. By clicking on the pillow, it should rotate to the next poster but you will see always parts of the previous/next poster.

My question is: How can I load the texture dynamically but also how to combine, load/unload posters on the run ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with papervision, but I'd look into simply supplying a `BitmapData` as texture, then you should be able to change that bitmap elsewhere in your app and have the texture update on the fly.